# C program to seperate data part of an elf file

Tags: c, linux, elf

Using readelf we can separate the data part from elf file(using shell)Is it possible to do the same with a C program?

Answer (score 2):

Use can use `libelf` for this purpose.

http://mdsp.googlecode.com/files/libelf-by-example-20100112.pdf

Answer (score 0):

`readelf` itself is program written in C. So the answer is yes.

If you are on a debian-like linux distribution, you can probably get the source of readelf by typing `apt-get source binutils` and see how it is done.